# Problems passing data to PHP from jQuery's AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im trying to pass an array of data to a PHP script using Jquery's AJAX; this is my JS:

```
var dataObject = {
    shippingDataRow: [{
        name: $('#shippingData_name').val(),
        street: $('#shippingData_street').val(),
        number: $('#shippingData_number').val(), 
    }]

};

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: { action: 'test', data: dataObject },
    cache: false,
    url: "php/post_test.php",  
});
```

And this is the PHP (just doing some tests, before I can write all procedures),

```
<?php
    function test(){
        $dataObject = $_POST['dataObject'];
        print_r( $dataObject );
    }
?>
```

In Chrome's Developer Tools, I can see the Status Code:200 OK; even all the array with the correct values, but when I open the php it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value of `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: Your code contains un-necessary commas, IE WILL complain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `$dataObject = $_POST['data'];`

You need to refer to the key of the posted data, not the value in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$dataObject = $_POST['dataObject'];
```

To:

```
$dataObject = $_POST['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post should be

```
$_POST['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling test().in anywhere.so,its cuess return 200ok but response null.echo anything in test_php.and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataObject = {
    shippingDataRow: {
        name: $('#shippingData_name').val(),
        street: $('#shippingData_street').val(),
        number: $('#shippingData_number').val()
    }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: { action: 'test', data: dataObject },
    cache: false,
    url: "php/post_test.php"
});
```

-

```
<?php
   $dataObject = $_POST['data'];
   print_r( $dataObject );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, $_POST['data'] will get you the data array.

Also, using $_REQUEST works well as it'll target both get/post requests.